# Rock Paper Scissors in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to finish an exercise from the book *Programming Principles and Practice using C++* exercise 10 chapter 4. The exercise is about to write a Rock Paper Scissor game, without using random function to let the computer "choose" between rock, paper or scissors, so you have to find a way to make the computer choice random. By the way that is not the point, the point is that my program keeps track of the player and the computer score. Now the problem is that I don't know how to assign the score. I came up with this:

```
enum types {ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS}
.
.
.
.
.
/* this is the part where i check the score */

 // all cases the player would lose
if (player == ROCK && computer == PAPER)    // paper beats rock
    ++computer_score;
else if (player == PAPER && computer == SCISSORS)   // scissors beat paper
    ++computer_score;
else if (player == SCISSORS && computer == ROCK)    // rock beats scissors
    ++computer_score;

else // all other cases the player would win
    ++player_score;
```

The problem is that I don't think that this piece of code is good. Is there a smarter way to do so ?

On internet I found a version made by the mathematician Nick Maclaren.
This is his code:

```
vector<string> words;
words.push_back("Rock");
words.push_back("Paper");
words.push_back("Scissors");

string guess;
cout << "Make a guess - Rock, Paper or Scissors\n";
while (cin >> guess) {
    int yours, mine; //-your- is the user choice. -mine- is the computer choice
    if (guess == "Rock")
        yours = 0;
    else if (guess  == "Paper")
        yours = 1;
    else if (guess  == "Scissors")
        yours = 2;
    else {
        cout << "Invalid guess - Rock used\n";
        yours = 0;
    }
    seed = (13*seed)%256;
    mine = seed%3;
    if (mine == yours) // draw
        cout << "Both guesses were " << words[yours] << " - no winner\n";
    else if ((3+mine-yours)%3 == 1) // computer wins
        cout << words[mine] << " beats " << words[yours] << " - I win\n";
    else // player wins
        cout << words[yours] << " beats " << words[mine] << " - you win\n";
}
```

By the way [here](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/C++/Exercises/Chapter_04/ex_04.cpp) is the link for the full code that he made. If you look at the entire code maybe you will understand more.

So he uses another approach but I don't understand this part of his code:

```
else if ((3+mine-yours)%3 == 1)//<-- I don't understand this conditional expression
    cout << words[mine] << " beats " << words[yours] <<
        " - I win\n";
```

I got that if the result of that expression is 1, the computer wins, else the winner is the player, but I don't understand the logic.

Comment: The first thing, at least with the code you've shown it's not true that in all other cases the player wins. You need a tie case as well, where the player and computer chose the same move. I would also say to combine the it to a single if for when the computer wins: if((ROCK==player && PAPER==computer) || (PAPER== player && SCISSORS == computer) || (SCISSORS==player&&ROCK==computer)) { ++computerScore; } else if((ROCK==computer&&PAPER==player) ... ) { ++playerScore; } else { /* tie */ }

Comment: Please don't use `define` to attach names to numbers, but use `enum`. I find using an `std::vector` here also a little overkill.

Comment: In addition, the algorithm of the mathematician is very compact, but at the same time very hard to understand. I suggest to be verbose and to check the outcomes against each other as everybody can understand that.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to look at is mine-yours mod 3, if mine-yours == 1 mod 3 then mine wins, if you are not convinced look at the three cases.

```
(3+mine-yours)%3
```

this looks at difference mod 3, the +3 is to make sure 3+mine-yours is positive before being evaluated by %

if you are unsure of % 
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

or what mod is 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: Ok I understand that he does +3 to make sure that the result is positive, but why +3 ? Because the types are 3 ? And why he does mine-yours and not yours-mine ?

Comment: because +3 will not change the answer mod 3 mathematically. As for the second question, the author could write `if ((3+yours-mine)%3 == 2)` , it is the difference mod 3 what matters and depends on how you have labelled rock paper scissors originally.

Answer (score 0):

This code reminds me why clever is the enemy of good.

I recommend you look at the answer from a similar question posted here: [Rock, Paper, Scissors Game Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204872/rock-paper-scissors-game-java)

Basically it's good to provide an interface of abstract class for the choice, provide implementations for the different valid choices, and let the class decide if it wins from another implementation or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First time using the stack overflow, it just happend that I got a same 
//homework as the question,so here is my code for reference

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
int computerChoice();
int userChoice();
int result(int user, int computer);
string choiceName(int choice);

int main()
{
    //declare variable
    int user, computer, winner;

    //keep playing if there is a tie
    do {
        user = userChoice();
        computer = computerChoice();
        winner = result(user, computer);
        cout << "User choice : " << choiceName(user) << "\tComputer Choice : " << choiceName(computer) << endl;
        if (winner == 1)
        {
            cout << "User win" << endl;
        }
        else if (winner == 2)
        {
            cout << "Computer win" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Tie" << endl;
        }
    } while (winner == 0);
    
    //exit system
    return 0;
}

//random generate a computer's choice 1-3
int computerChoice() {
    srand(time(0));
    return rand() % 3 + 1;
}

//get user input 1-3
int userChoice() {
    int userChoice;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
        cout << "1.Rock" << endl;
        cout << "2.Paper" << endl;
        cout << "3.Scissors" << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;
        if (userChoice > 3 || userChoice < 1) {
            cout << "Invalid choice, try again" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return userChoice;
}

// 0 - tie      1- user win     2 - computer win
//rules
int result(int userChoice, int computerChoice) {
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (userChoice == 3 || computerChoice == 3) 
    {
        return userChoice < computerChoice ? 1 : 2;
    }
    else 
    {
        return userChoice > computerChoice ? 1 : 2;
    }
}

//match the choice name
string choiceName(int choice) {
    if (choice == 1) 
    {
        return "Rock";
    }
    else if (choice == 2) 
    {
        return "Paper";
    }
    else 
    {   
        return "Scissors";
    }
}
```