# How to create methods for a rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: java

I was assigned an assignment where we have to create a rock, paper, scissors game (this is beginning programming class that uses java) with methods and return statements. I am having trouble writing all the necessary methods w/h return statements needed to run the program. Here is the prompt:

> Write a program that lets the user play the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors against the computer. The program should work as follows.
>
> 1. When the program begins, a random number in the range of 1 through 3 is generated. If the number is 1, then the computer has chosen rock. If the number is 2, then the computer has chosen paper. If the number is 3, then the computer has chosen scissors. (Don’t display the computer’s choice yet.)
> 2. The user enters his or her choice of “rock”, “paper”, or “scissors” at the keyboard. (You can use a menu if you prefer.)
> 3. The computer’s choice is displayed.
> 4. A winner is selected according to the following rules:
>
>    - If one player chooses rock and the other player chooses scissors, then rock wins. (The rock smashes the scissors.)
>    - If one player chooses scissors and the other player chooses paper, then scissors wins. (Scissors cuts paper.)
>    - If one player chooses paper and the other player chooses rock, then paper wins. (Paper wraps rock.)
>    - If both players make the same choice, the game must be played again to determine the winner. Be sure to divide the program into methods that perform each major task.

I've tried declaring many variables (strings and ints) pithing and outside the methods. I've importer scanners and random. I have two methods so far. My problem to be honest is not really knowing when to use loops, methods, etc. It's all sort of jumbled.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class rockPaperScissors
{
   public static int generateComputer(Random rc)
   {
       int n = rc.nextInt(3) + 1;
       return n; 
   }

   public static int playerChoice(Scanner sc)
   {
      System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 1 and 3:         ");
  int pc = sc.nextInt();

  while(pc < 1 || pc > 3)
  {
     System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 1 and 3: ");
     pc = sc.nextInt();
  }  

   return pc;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int cp;
     int po;

     Random rc = new Random();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


     cp = generateComputer(rc);
     po = playerChoice(sc);
  }
}
```

I'm new at this so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rock, Paper, Scissors Game Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204872/rock-paper-scissors-game-java)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add some if statements to decide whether the user win, or the computer win, or it's a draw and then print the result to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code and a brief explanation afterwards.

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    private static int getComputerRandomChoice() {
        Random rc = new Random();
        int n = rc.nextInt(3) + 1;
        return n;
    }
    private static int playerChoice() {
        System.out.println("== Rock Paper Scissors ==\n" +
                "== Rock : 1 ==\n"  +
                "== Paper : 2 ==\n"  +
                "== Scissors : 3 ==\n");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pc = 0;
        while(pc<1 ||0 pc>3){
            System.out.println("Please make your choice (between 1 and 3):");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            try {
                pc = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input (not an integer)");
            }
        }
        return pc;
    }

    private static String getWinner(int cp, int po){
        if (cp==1){
            if (po==1){
                return "DRAW";
            }else if(po==2){
                return "USER";
            }else{
                return "COMPUTER";
            }
        }else if (cp==2){
            if (po==1){
                return "COMPUTER";
            }else if(po==2){
                return "DRAW";
            }else{
                return "USER";
            }
        }else{
            if (po==1){
                return "USER";
            }else if(po==2){
                return "COMPUTER";
            }else{
                return "DRAW";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cp = getComputerRandomChoice();
        int po = playerChoice();
        String winner = getWinner(cp, po);
        System.out.println("The computer chose: " + cp);
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + winner);
    }

}
```

You should name your classes with CamelCase and capital first letter `RockPaperScissors`.

Also your method names should mean something for example `generateComputer` vs. `getComputerRandomChoice()`.

You had created a Random object outside of the generateComputer method, while this random object was not used at any other place of your code, so I placed it inside the getComputerRandomChoice() method, so this method's object(s) are only visible and used in that method for a specific purpose.

Same for Scanner, the Scanner object is inside the playerChoice method as there is no other place where a user input is needed. For Scanner, note that I have changed the `nextInt()` to `nextLine()` because the nextInt gets the next integer even if the user enteres `5 6` with a space, the next int will not fail as it will take the first int token as input. With `nextLine()` your code will read the full line and will try to parse into an Integer later (`Integer.parseInt(input)').

The user input is inside a while loop, and the code will exit the loop only when a valid input is entered.

Finally the getWinner method takes the 2 inputs (computer's choice, player's choice) and applies the business logic of the game using if else statements. Alternatively you can use `switch()`.